# General resolution in first order logic

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, first-order-logic

Assuming you have a formula in first order logic like

> > $$(\forall_x p(x) \land \forall_x q(x)) \rightarrow \forall_x(p(x) \land q(x))$$
> >     (which seems valid?)

Converting the formula to CNF:

> $$(\neg p(x) \vee \neg q(y) \vee p(z)) \land (\neg p(x) \vee \neg q(y) \vee q(z)) $$

I don't see how I can apply general resolution to get the empty clause in this case which puzzles me since I believe the formula is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly point out, the original formula is valid (in every model either there is some element for which p or q doesn't hold, or p and q hold for all elements).

To prove that your formula is valid, you cannot use resolution directly. Recall that with resolution, you can derive the empty clause from a clause set iff the clause set is unsatisfiable. **Your formula is valid iff its negation is unsatisfiable**. So to prove your formula is valid, you have to derive the empty clause from the clause set corresponding to the negation of your formula.

Let $\varphi$ be your original formula. $$\lnot \varphi \equiv \forall_x \forall_y \exists_z (px \land qy \land (\lnot pz \lor \lnot qz))$$
Skolemization replaces $z$ by a function symbol $f(x,y)$:
$$\lnot \varphi \equiv_{SAT} \forall_x \forall_y (px \land qy \land (\lnot pfxy \lor \lnot qfxy))$$
The corresponding clause set:
$$\{\{px\},\{qy\},\{\lnot pfxy, \lnot qfxy\}\}$$
From there it should be straight-forward to derive the empty clause:

- Apply renaming $\nu_1 = \{x/x_1\}$ to $\{px\}$, yielding $\{px_1\}$, then
  resolve $\{p x_1 \}$ with $\{ \lnot pfxy, \lnot qfxy\}$ by $\sigma_1 = \{ x_1 / fxy\}$, yielding $\{\lnot q fxy\}$
- Apply renaming $\nu_2 = \{y / y_1\}$ to $\{qy\}$, yielding $\{qy_1\}$, then resolve $\{qy_1\}$ with $\{ \lnot qfxy \}$ by $\sigma_2 = \{y_1/fxy\}$, yielding the empty clause $\Box$

In conclusion, we have shown by resolution that $\lnot \varphi$ is unsatisfiable. Therefore $\varphi$ is valid.